# 3D Point Cloud Generation using Tensorflow and PointNet

Tags: python, tensorflow, 3d

So I have a corpus of data that consist of a set of specific 3D point Clouds. I’d like to use that data to train a NN so that it can create its own unique 3D point cloud data for mesh conversion later down the road.

Here is what my research has revealed so far: that there is a library called PointNet:  https://github.com/charlesq34/pointnet
It’s for deep learning on point sets or 3D point clouds and it uses Tensorflow.

What I don’t understand is, after training a NN, how do you use the NN to then create a 3D Point Cloud based on it’s training?

Answer (score 1):

The input to the network is Nx3 matrix, where N is number of the points. 
[image: Pointnet architecture]

As far as I understood this method has 3 different use cases. One is classification: given point cloud of a single object estimate the class of the given object. The second is to make part segmentation: for each point in the input mesh model decide the point's "label". And the third case given the whole room (indoor) segment it by objects (it can be trained to segment such objects like chair etc.).

Given the image here you can see that the input is Nx3 (but in the paper they use Nx9: 3 xyz coordinates, then rgb coordinated (if the rgb image is also available) and then normalized xyz coordinates (in range [0,1]).

The output in the third case is a matrix nxm where m is number of classes.

Im not sure what is your aim, but it seems like you want to create another point cloud given the original point cloud. But this algorithm is mainly for segmentation or classification.

Answer (score 0):

This model is for identifying things rather than creating things.  To generate 3D objects, you need to implement the conv2d_transpose by yourself.  See how the point_cluods is converted to a 2D image here: https://github.com/charlesq34/pointnet/blob/master/models/pointnet_cls.py.

You can kind of do that reverse to get your point cloud back from the out of the conv2d_transpose.

The idea is here.  It's not that easy.  I am also searching for some codes available online.